# How frequent and regular should protein intake be?

Tags: protein

I have a varied, aiming for low-fat vegetarian diet where I eat sometimes vegetables with a bit of bread, sometimes meat industrial substitutes (I try to reduce them), sometimes pasta or rice, sometimes tofu, sometimes leguminous such as lentils, chickpeas, split peas. I can have a bit of cheese, and usually eat soy "yogurts".

I have meals where I have very little protein intakes and other where I would have more than someone else eating meat. I eat very little for breakfast so I do two real meals a day.

I'm concerned about my equilibrium if I don't eat proteins for a day, but I'm really unsure when I should start worrying, and if eating more proteins the meal after "compensates" or not.

So how frequent and regular should protein intakes be?

Answer (score 1):

Many sports nutrition sites provide guidance to nutrient intake, but suggestions are typically linked to a person's activities and objectives, such as stamina, strength, muscular mass gain etc.  PubMed provides a few reports including [Per meal dose and frequency of protein consumption is associated with lean mass and muscle performance](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27086196/)